# Disable Text on Windows Phone 7 Icon

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, icons

I've written a couple of simple Windows Phone icons, and I need to disable the text on the icon that gets pinned to the start screen. I can't find anything on this through Google. I've tried just removed the Title text and using a space, but neither of those are valid. I know the Facebook app does this, so I know it's possible, even if it's only with a closer partnership with Microsoft...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can edit the WMAppManifest.xml directly to set the  tag to the desired space or empty string instead of using the [Project].[Properties].[Application] Form. This has worked for me as recent as 08/11 (and passed MS certification). Note also that when using Live tile Refresh, empty string is valid (example below)

```
    private void RefreshApplicationTile()
    {
        ShellTile tile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First();
        if (tile != null) {
            StandardTileData NewTileData = new StandardTileData
            {
                Title = String.Empty,
                BackgroundImage = new Uri(@"/Background.png", UriKind.Relative),
                BackTitle = String.Empty,
                BackBackgroundImage = new Uri(@"/BackBackground.png", UriKind.Relative),
    ....
            };
            tile.Update(NewTileData);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just note that ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First(); will give you the main application tile. If you want to change the text on additional tiles you generate you'll need to query the ActiveTiles collection and find the specific tile you want to update. This is usually done by looking at the Uri for the tile.